# Quest mode in Bejeweled 3

Tags: bejeweled-3

I am now at 83% on the quest mode with all options filled in relic #1. What do I need to do now? Do I continue to try and get every green dot in each relic to completion? I read elsewhere here something about how you needed to get to 80% completion in quest mode to get BEYOND the chair. I got beyond 80% but I am not seeing anything else open.

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 levels (relics) in the Quest Mode. Once you complete enough puzzles for a relic, you can pass to the next one. The Chair relic is the last one, and once you complete enough puzzles in total (i.e. more than 80%) including the Chair relic, you finish the Quest Mode.

Comment: I am at 92%. First 3 relics all complete, 2 games left on crown and 1 left on chair. BUT despite I am over 80%, I do not get the left arrow to proceed beyond QUEST mode to ??? Not sure if I am supposed to get the upper left arrow on QUEST mode to even engage for anything. It might be only to move across the 5 relics?? I only need 2 reg badges and 3 more elite badges. Guess when that is done, game is over? Kind of boarded at this point now. Looking for more for $20!

Comment: Seeing now in my badge area that I need to as of yet COMPLETE QUEST mode to get Hero's Welcome badge. So ? then still is about completion of Quest mode - if completion of Quest mode is 80% or > in Quest mode play with all 5 artifacts revealed (which I have and outlined above in detail of what my Quest mode now shows), how come since according to all I read says I have completed Quest mode, why don't I have the Hero's Welcome Badge?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is on your side, but I have completed the Quest Mode just as I explained in my answer. What you can try is to complete *all* puzzles to see if the game lets you finish the mode.